# How to get the first column in ag grid with example

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ag-grid-angular

I wanted to pass first column as an argument so wanted to know how to get the first column in ag grid.

I wanted to get the first column

Comment: Please add some code of what you have tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.